# Eleições para Moderador 2015 - Indicação dos moderadores atuais

Tags: debate, eleição

Ao ver a página das eleições notei que os moderadores atuais (@bfavaretto e @utluiz) não lançaram suas candidaturas.

Gostaria de saber se o sistema não permite a reeleição ou se os mesmos que não estão interessados, visto que até aqui eles tem feito um bom trabalho.

Comment: Ainda faltam 8 horas. Acredito que ainda vão aparecer mais candidatos. Deve ser estratégia de eleição, :)

Comment: O sistema permite que ele se candidatem sim. E eu espero que eles se candidatem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Só existem duas possíveis respostas para isso:

1. Os atuais moderadores resolveram "fazer suspense", acompanhando o processo sem falar nada e deixar a própria candidatura para a última hora, se for o caso.
2. Na verdade eles foram trancafiados pela SE num porão (num esquema tipo bolivianos em SP) onde são forçados a passar mais de 16 horas por dia moderando o site. O Gabe nada mais é do que um carrasco misturado com relações públicas. Os novos eleitos integrarão o time existente.

Não pode ser nada mais a não ser uma dessas alternativas.

Comment: **VAI TRABALHAR**

Comment: Vai se candidatar!  (Sem negrito, pq não sou chefe igual ao @Gabe. kkk)

Comment: Óbviamente a resposta 2 é a correta. E digo mais, os novos moderadores se juntarão em um porão do porão dos atuais, ainda mais obscuro, e terão de trabalhar não 16h mas 20 horas por dia.

Comment: Shhhhh! Assim você vai assustar os candidatos! Precisamos de mais gente para poder executar nosso plano de fuga. Agora é melhor irmos moderar uns flags, ou vamos ficar sem almoço.

Comment: ahahahahah TOP :D

Comment: Faltou mencionar que os que não forem eleitos irão formar o grupo da oposição, que terão como objetivo infernizar a vida dos eleitos 24h por dia.